# Is it possible to change the callback object after the WCF Client object is created?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a situation where my initial service connection is maintained by a serviceConnection class.

I would like to dynamically change the object that implements the callback interface at a later date.

Is this possible in WCF?

I create my initial callback the standard way like this :

MainClient = new ServiceClient(new InstanceContext(serverCallback), binding, endpointAddress);

Later, can I replace the callback class serverCallback with another class that implements the correct interface without breaking the connection and re-creating it with the constructor?